# Runtime Const in Golang

Tags: go, constants

In some languages, such as Java and C++, constants can be created and then assigned their value during the constructor (and then not changed after that).  Is there any way to do this in Golang so that a constant whose value won't be known until runtime can be created?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Constants in go are set at compile time, see the relevant section in the docs here: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#constants

> Constants in Go are just that—constant. They are created at compile time, even when defined as locals in functions, and can only be numbers, characters (runes), strings or booleans. Because of the compile-time restriction, the expressions that define them must be constant expressions, evaluatable by the compiler. For instance, 1<<3 is a constant expression, while math.Sin(math.Pi/4) is not because the function call to math.Sin needs to happen at run time.

Answer (score 4):

As stated, there are no constructs supporting runtime constants in Go backed by the language spec or the Go runtime.

You can simpulate runtime constants though with unexported fields and with a "getter" method, e.g.:

```
package wrapper

type Immutable struct {
    value int
}

func (i Immutable) Get() int { // You may choose between pointer or value receiver
    return i.value
}

func New(value int) Immutable {
    return Immutable{value}
}
```

You can create values of `Immutable` with the `New()` constructor-like function, and *no one** outside of package `wrapper` will be able to modify the wrapped `int` value (`Immutable.value`).

(*Note: *no one* means no one who is not touching package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/), but that doesn't count. Even in Java you can change values of `final` attributes using Java reflection.)

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. constants can only hold strings and numbers known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using an unexported struct and define functions that use that unexported type specifically.

```
// ./vendor/structstuff/structstuff.go
package structstuff

type constVal struct {
    val int
}

func (c *constVal) Value() int {
    return c.val
}

var ExportedVal constVal

func init() {
    ExportedVal.val = 43
}

func CallFunc(c constVal) int {
    return c.val
}

// ./main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "structstuff"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(structstuff.ExportedVal.Value())
    fmt.Println(structstuff.CallFunc(structstuff.ExportedVal))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function at Runtime to act just like constants as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    
    // Define a Runtime constant
    
    pi := func() float64 { return 3.141592653589793238 }
    
    // Use the constant
    
    x := pi() * 123
    
    // Print the result
    
    fmt.Println("X = ", x)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Q0dGfwL_Y4P